# Error in checking password match

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a trouble in checking if the password is match with the confirm password.

this is the modal form for user to enter the password

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-hide="hideField">
 <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required ng-minlength="8">
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.password.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-hide="hideField">
 <label class="control-label" for="confirmpassword">Re-enter Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" ng-model="user.confirmpassword" required ng-minlength="8" >
   <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
</div>
```

this is button to submit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="!allowSubmit(addUser)" ng-click="add();">Save</button>
```

what i want is that, before submitting the form, password that user enter must match with the confirm password. I am doing something like this. but it is not checking the password as i wish. Appreciate your kind help.

```
$dialogScope.add = function() {

 if ($dialogScope.user.password != $dialogScope.user.confirmpassword)
    {
     dialogScope.errorMessage = "Password does not match!"
     }
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rZNEqiDYmVJiC79txh4K?p=preview provide plunker link @RayonDabre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-submit="add()"` on the parent form and remove `ng-click="add();"` from the submit button.

```
$dialogScope.add = function() {
   if ($dialogScope.user.password != $dialogScope.user.confirmpassword) {
       dialogScope.errorMessage = "Password does not match!";
       return false;
   }

   // Do what you want to do after for form submission
};
```

Comment: its working.but i still use ng-click="add();". thanks for your kind help